# .NET MVC : Calling RedirectToAction passing a model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I got a view `List.aspx` that is bound to the class `Kindergarten`

In the controller:

```
public ActionResult List(int Id)
{
  Kindergarten k = (from k1 in _kindergartensRepository.Kindergartens
                    where k1.Id == Id
                    select k1).First();

  return View(k);
}
```

That works.

But this doesn't

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Add(...)
{
  //...
  Kindergarten k = ...
  return RedirectToAction("List", k);
}
```

How should I redirect to the list view, passing k as the model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you just need to call view like

> return RedirectToAction("List", new
>   {id});

with id you need to populate the  Kindergarten.

Answer (score 56):

I don't believe ModelBinding exists when using RedirectToAction. Your best options, however, is to use the TempData collection to store the object, and retrieve it in the following action.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Add(...)
{
  //...
  Kindergarten k = ...
  TempData["KG"] = k;
  return RedirectToAction("List");
}
```

In your List Action

```
public ActionResult List()
{

   Kindergarten k = (Kindergarten)TempData["KG"];
   // I assume you need to do some stuff here with the object, 
   // otherwise this action would be a waste as you can do this in the Add Action
  return View(k);
}
```

Note: TempData collection only holds object for a single subsequent redirect. Once you make any redirect from Add, TempData["KG"] will be null (unless you repopulate it)

Comment: you shouldn't be using MVC like this.

Comment: It implies there is to much logic in your actions.  Business logic should be in a separate layer (services) and your action should call this logic and then redirect to the appropriate view.  You shouldn't get into a position where you need to do the above if your app is well designed.

Comment: Storing objects in memory doesn't mean you're app is not well designed. There are use cases for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1664269/160823. It may not be ideal in this exact implementation, but it's not inherently incorrect to use.

Comment: If MVC would allow use to send to the `public ActionResult MethodName(Model record)` overload of different controllers using the `RedirectToAction` method, I would be happy not to use this...but if I've done the work to load the Record in one controller, I don't want to pass an ID and then repeat the work in a second location.  TempData gives me a suitable workaround.  Thanks.

Comment: ModelBinding does occur on a RedirectToAction

Comment: When multiple website instances are Load Balanced, theoretically every request might arrive to different instance. In such case, storing local state is a bad idea. Better to pass it as an argument or make it shared.

Answer (score 18):

I'm not sure you want to call `RedirectToAction` because that will just cause k to be set again.

I think you want to call `View` and pass in the name of the view and your model.

```
return View("List", k);
```

Comment: Oh but what if the view is on another controller?

Comment: When its looking for a View, it'll check the View\Controller\ folder, if it doesn't find it there, it checks the Shared folder. If you want to access a view across multiple controllers, put it in the Shared folder.

Comment: Also, I haven't tested this, but I suppose you could also try giving it a direct path: return View("~/Views/Controller/List.ascx"). Although I believe using the shared folder is preferable.

Comment: This is correct however the URL will still say Add, not List.

Comment: Also, this violates the Post-Redirect-Get pattern. If the page is refreshed after returning the view then the original Post is resent, which may cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

As Brandon said, you probably want to use `return View("List", Id)` instead, but the problem you're having is that you're passing `k`, your model, to a method that accepts an `int` as its parameter.

Think of `RedirectToAction` as a method call.