# Difficulty passing object from one controller to anothher

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to pass an object from one controller to another controller, but it is not behaving in the way that I would like it to. In the following `ApplicantMainController`, I am instantiating an object called `ApplicationQuestions` (which contains a `List<ApplicationQuestion>` object as one of its members) and then attempting to pass it via the `RedirectToAction` method call:

```
public ActionResult FormAction(FormCollection collection)
{
    if (collection["cmdSearch"] != null)
    {
        // more code above...

        ApplicationQuestions questions = new ApplicationQuestions();

        MultipleChoiceQuestion q1 = new MultipleChoiceQuestion("Can you lift 50 pounds?");
        MultipleChoiceQuestion q2 = new MultipleChoiceQuestion("Are you at least 18 years of age?");
        MultipleChoiceQuestion q3 = new MultipleChoiceQuestion("Are you legally able to work in the US?");
        MultipleChoiceQuestion q4 = new MultipleChoiceQuestion("Have you ever been convicted of a felony?");

        q1.AddPossibleAnswer(1, new Answer("Yes", true));
        q1.AddPossibleAnswer(2, new Answer("No", false));
        q2.AddPossibleAnswer(1, new Answer("Yes", true));
        q2.AddPossibleAnswer(2, new Answer("No", false));
        q3.AddPossibleAnswer(1, new Answer("Yes", true));
        q3.AddPossibleAnswer(2, new Answer("No", false));
        q4.AddPossibleAnswer(1, new Answer("Yes", false));
        q4.AddPossibleAnswer(2, new Answer("No", true));

        questions.AddQuestion(q1);
        questions.AddQuestion(q2);
        questions.AddQuestion(q3);
        questions.AddQuestion(q4);

        // not sure how to pass the object here??
        return RedirectToAction("Apply", "ApplicantApply", new { model = questions });
    }
}
```

When I redirect to the controller, it appears to make it:

```
private ApplicationQuestions m_questions;

// more code ...

public ActionResult Apply(ApplicationQuestions questions)
{
    m_questions = questions;
    return RedirectToAction("NextQuestion", "ApplicantApply");
}
```

However, though the reference is now bound to the parameter passed to the `Apply` method, the debugger tells me that the reference to the collection `questions` does not contain any elements, though clearly the caller passed a collection with four elements. I think I am misunderstanding how this works -- what is the proper way to communicate objects between controllers like this?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use TempData to hold the object during the redirect.

```
TempData["MyCoolData"] = questions;
return RedirectToAction("Apply", "ApplicantApply");
```

Then grab the object out of TempData in the other action:

```
m_questions = (ApplicationQuestions)TempData["MyCoolData"];
```

See [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324044/net-mvc-calling-redirecttoaction-passing-a-model) for more information.

Comment: Would this last assignment statement be performed in the `ActionResult` method that is the redirect destination?

Comment: Yes, it would.  I've updated the answer to show that a bit better.